# How to know the data structure in d3.js examples of Mike Bostock

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

How to know the structure of the jsons in Mike Bostock examples such as this (after beeing manipulated using d3):

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

My goal is to implement it with my own dummy array of JSON objects without loading csv data. But I can't figure out how the jsons should look like.

Data manipulation from Mike Bostock:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
```

I already tried to save the csv locally and run the code above in node.js command but it didn't work. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation for d3 it shows an example of how a CSV is parsed into an array of objects. Here is an example CSV file:

```
Year,Make,Model,Length
1997,Ford,E350,2.34
2000,Mercury,Cougar,2.38
```

The resulting JavaScript array is:

```
[
  {"Year": "1997", "Make": "Ford", "Model": "E350", "Length": "2.34"},
  {"Year": "2000", "Make": "Mercury", "Model": "Cougar", "Length": "2.38"}
]
```

(from https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/master/README.md#dsv_parse)

That means that in your example the first data element would look like this:

```
[
  {"State": "AL", "Under 5 Years": "310504","5 to 13 Years": "552339","14 to 17 Years": "259034","18 to 24 Years": "450818","25 to 44 Years": "1231572","45 to 64 Years": "1215966","65 Years and Over": "641667"}
]
```

Or like this in an easier to read format:

```
[
  {
    "State": "AL", 
    "Under 5 Years": "310504",
    "5 to 13 Years": "552339",
    "14 to 17 Years": "259034",
    "18 to 24 Years": "450818",
    "25 to 44 Years": "1231572",
    "45 to 64 Years": "1215966",
    "65 Years and Over": "641667"
  }
]
```

Your best bet would be to copy Bostock's CSV into a JSON to CSV converter ([this one has worked for me](http://www.csvjson.com/csv2json) but there are many others) and then use the JSON in your local code.

If you do use the D3 CSV load functions you will have a hard time doing it from a local file without a simple server because of cross origin request errors.

Also, I don't exactly know what you mean when you say you ran this as a node.js command--I think you probably want to include your javascript and the json object in a '.js' file and link that to an html file, or just inline your javascript in the html file if it is a simple project (like Bostock does in the visual you linked)

Comment: thank you. I used your suggestion (CSV to JSON online converter)!